# Removing non-alphanumeric characters from a string

Tags: php, regex, user-input

I have a string in PHP and I want it to match the regex [A-Za-Z0-9]. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am assuming you meant, `a-z` instead of `a-Z`, inside of your regex, but you can use [**`preg_replace`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $string);
```

It takes as arguments the pattern (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`), replacement (`""`) and the subject (`$string`) and returns the new string (`$new_string`)

Answer (score 4):

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 3):

`\W` is a shortcut for `[^a-Z0-9_]`. May not be extremely helpful as it allows underscores too, but thought I'd let you know.